# IdentityServer 4 and ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I should make application for user authentication by IdentityServer 4 and ADFS, but I don't know how to make it and I can't find any examples on [official IdentityServer docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Can anybody explain me, how does it work and how to integrate IdentityServer 4 and ADFS?

Answer (score 1):

See if this can help [Identity server and Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978033/identityserver-4-and-azure-ad) and also based on the [distributed Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/november/using-active-directory-federation-services-2-0-in-identity-solutions) via ADFS I think it should not be that different from (except API calls). All in all the process should be same.

Also for a good discussion on [ADFS vs AAD](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory/adfs-vs-azure-ad-for-sso/m-p/64414), please have a look here.