# Successfactors SSO with Dotnet API and IdentityServer 4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, saml, sap-successfactors

I have an Dotnet Core API application which uses IdentityServer4 as IDP. The frontend is built in Angular.

Now, I need to connect to Successfactors of one of my client. I understand SAML is the best federation protocol there.

Please suggest what should be my approach here and relevant tutorials that I can follow. I am not getting good google results.

Comment: Somebody, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Microsoft does not have one. So you need to integrate a third-party product.

There are a number of examples [here](https://authory.com/RoryBraybrook?collection=Identity-Server&view=thumbnail).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I also went through lot of documentation and found more details about this integration.
So the client uses Azure AD Free Pass (synced with on-premises). My SPA is interacting with Web API and IdentityServer. My IdentityServer has to connect with the Azure AD (free pass through version) through SAML and get the user validated to be able to generate token.
I found IdentityServer's implementation of Rock Solid. But it requires a license which is very costly. Is there a open source version available?

Comment: I am actually a noob and hence struggling to even form my questions with right words. Please help

Comment: Why does idsrv have to connect with Azure AD via SAML? Rather use OpenID Connect. That's out the box and free.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978033/identityserver-4-and-azure-ad

Comment: Thank you so much rbrayb! You are a saviour ❤